# AT command for USSD code

Tags: c, at-command

this is the code i am currently using to try send a USSD code to the modem.

```
static void __display_data_balance(void) {
      const STR* vodacomUSSD = "*111*502#";
      const STR* mtnUSSD = "*141*1#";
      const STR* cellcUSSD = "*101#";
      const STR* telkomUSSD = "*188#";
      const STR* virginMobileUSSD = "*101#";

      USHORT state;
      USHORT error = SSD_STATE_GOOD;
      BOOL done = FALSE;

      USHORT size = 0;
      STR* ussdCommand = NULL;

      BYTE length;
      BYTE buffer[64];

      for (state = 1; !error && !done; state++) {
         printf("[__display_data_balance] state = %d\n", state);
         printf("Buffer = %s\n", buffer);
         switch (state) {
            default:
               error = SSD_STATE_CORRUPT;
               break;

            case 1:
               //error = CTOS_GSMOpen(115200, TRUE);
               break;

            case 2:
               error = CTOS_GSMQueryOperatorName(buffer, &length);
               break;

            case 3:
               printf("[__display_data_balance] buffer = %s\n", buffer);
               printf("[__display_data_balance] length = %d\n", length);
               CTOS_LCDGTextOut(110, 210, buffer, d_LCD_FONT_12x24, FALSE);

               if (strncmp("\"VodaCom-SA\"", buffer, length) == 0) {
                  ussdCommand = (STR*) vodacomUSSD;
               } else if (strncmp("\"MTN-SA\"", buffer, length) == 0) {
                  ussdCommand = (STR*) mtnUSSD;
               } else if (strncmp("\"Cellc-SA\"", buffer, length) == 0) {
                  ussdCommand = (STR*) cellcUSSD;
               } else if (strncmp("\"Telkom-SA\"", buffer, length) == 0) {
                  ussdCommand = (STR*) telkomUSSD;
               } else if (strncmp("\"VirginMobile-SA\"", buffer, length) == 0) {
                  ussdCommand = (STR*) virginMobileUSSD;
               } else {
                  error = SSD_STATE_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
               }

               if (ussdCommand) {
                  sprintf(buffer, "AT+CUSD=1,\"%s\",15\r", ussdCommand);
                  error = CTOS_GSMSendATCmd(buffer, strlen(buffer), 2000);
                  //USHORT CTOS_GSMSendATCmd(BYTE *baCmd, ULONG ulLen, ULONG ulTimeout);
               }
               break;

            case 4:

               size = sizeof (buffer);
               error = CTOS_GSMRecvData(buffer, &size);
               //USHORT CTOS_GSMRecvData ( BYTE *baData, USHORT *pusLen );
               break;

            case 5:
               printf("[__display_data_balance] buffer = %s\n", buffer);
               printf("[__display_data_balance] length = %d\n", length);
               CTOS_LCDGTextOut(40, 270, buffer, d_LCD_FONT_12x24, FALSE);

               //error = CTOS_GSMClose();
               break;

            case 6:
               done = TRUE;

               break;
         }
```

I would Like to know what it is I am doing wrong please I am fairly new to programing and would like some assistance please.

I have added the entire function.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Wow!  Someone is still using a modem?

Comment: @SGeorgiades What would you use instead of GSM modems for world-wide wireless communication to electronic devices? Pigeon post?

Comment: Where are the declarations of `size`, `buffer` and `ussdCommand`?   I suspect you have a problem with the `size = sizeof(buffer)`, as since `buffer` is likely a pointer, this will just give the size of the pointer.  You probably want a `#define` for the buffer size, then use that `#define`d value when you declare `buffer`, and again when you assign `size` before calling `CTOS_GSMRecvData`.

Comment: It is for a POS terminal to display the data balance it returns AT+CUSD=1,"*111*502#",12 because the ISP is Vodacom but not the data balance. Here are the other declarations: USHORT state;
      USHORT error = SSD_STATE_GOOD;
      BOOL done = FALSE;

      USHORT size = 0;
      STR* ussdCommand = NULL;

      BYTE length;
      BYTE buffer[64];

Comment: Sorry, @Lundin... I just haven't seen the AT commands in my own realm of experience for almost 25 years.

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong in your code? Please modify your question and show the declarations of all variables involved.

Comment: @DanielBasson for clarifications please don't post code in comments but [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16372495).

Comment: I have added in the entire function

Comment: @SGeorgiades AT commands are popular for any form of wireless modules that have a UART interface. UART in itself is of course a stone age technology though... it is sad that designers keep such old junk in new products instead of better technologies like SPI or CAN, but that's just how it is.

Comment: My output from  from the CTOS_GSMRecvData is AT+CUSD=1,"111*502#",12 and not the desired data balance

Comment: [off-topic] Is there any valid reason for using STR and BYTE? Are they different ? Can they be different ? Can they differ from ((un)signed) char ?

Comment: No specific reason

Comment: @DanielBasson please edit your question and tell us what exactly you expect and what you actually get.

Answer (score 1):

> My output from from the CTOS_GSMRecvData is AT+CUSD=1,"111*502#",12 and not the desired data balance

A few things, that you can check.

- Read the current state of presentation of an unsolicited result code, by issuing **AT+CUSD?**
- Issue **AT+CUSD=1** to enable presentation
- Next issue **AT+CUSD=1,"111*502#",12**
- Please note, the response from network is asynchronous, I am hoping the **CTOS_GSMRecvData** is implemented to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with those declarations, you will want to set `size` to 64, instead of `sizeof(buffer)`, or better yet...

```
#define BUFSIZE (64)
    :
    :
BYTE buffer[BUFSIZE];
    :
    :
size = BUFSIZE;
CTOS_GSMRecvData(buffer, &size);//Receive data from GSM module.
    :
    :
```

And hopefully that is a typo... `ussCommand` should be `STR*`, not `STR`.

Also, where is `length` set... hopefully it is something like `length = strlen(buffer)`... or perhaps you should just use `strcmp`, where length is not required.

Though this is not a bug, it is usual convention when using any of the `strcmp` family of functions to compare with a string constant, to put the variable first and the string constant second... just like most people would write `if ( x == 1 ) ...`, rather than `if ( 1 == x )...`